# How to select a random vector

Tags: r, vector, random, sampling

I have 4 vectors that contain integers.

I want to perform calculations based on 2 of the vectors, selected randomly.

I tried creating a new vector containing all the vectors, but `sample()` only gives me the first element of each vector.

My vectors if it helps:

```
A <- c(4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0)
B <- c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)
C <- c(6, 6, 2, 2, 2, 2)
D <- c(5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1)
```

The output I wanted is for example: `A, B` or `B, D` or `D, A` etc.

A thousand thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to sample from the names of your vectors, rather from the vectors themselves e.g. `choices <- c("A", "B", "C", "D") sample(x = choices, size = 2)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easier to do if you store your vectors in a list:

```
vecs <- list(
  A = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0),
  B = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3),
  C = c(6, 6, 2, 2, 2, 2),
  D = c(5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1)
)

idx <- sample(1:length(vecs), 2, replace = F)

sampled <- vecs[idx]

sampled

$D
[1] 5 5 5 1 1 1

$B
[1] 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

You can then access your two sampled vectors, regardless of their names, with `sampled[[1]]` and `sampled[[2]]`.

Answer (score 3):

You first need make a [list](/questions/tagged/list) or a [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe), on which you can do `sample()`. `size=` says the number of vectors that you want in each sample, which is `2` here.

**LIST**

```
> LIST <- list(A, B, C, D) 
> sample(LIST, size = 2)
[[1]]
[1] 3 3 3 3 3 3

[[2]]
[1] 4 4 4 4 0 0
```

**Dataframe**

```
> df <- data.frame(A, B, C, D)
> sample(df, size = 2)
  B C
1 3 6
2 3 6
3 3 2
4 3 2
5 3 2
6 3 2
```

I think you were sampling on the wrong object.

Answer (score 1):

Make a list:

```
LIST = list(A,B,C,D)
names(LIST) = c("A","B","C","D")
```

This gives you a sample of 2 from the list

```
sample(LIST,2)
```

To add them for example, do:

```
Reduce("+",sample(LIST,2))
```